# Iterating through rows in DataTables using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, mysql, datatable, iteration

Essentially the problem is that I am getting duplicate results in my DataTable.

In my application, the user will enter a value and that value will return an array of objects from the database and those records will then populate in the DataTable. Currently the issue that I am having is that all the records that are in the table are all the same.

**There should be 100 different records in the DataTable, instead there is 100 of the exact same record.** I am not seeing any examples that show how to iterate though an array of objects from a database, in a way that in can be handled by the DataTable.

I should be able to use [rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows.add()) but that does not have anything displaying in the table and the other option I saw was [rows().every()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/rows().every()) which does not have an example similar to what I am doing.

**Any references, resources or insight will be very helpful. Thanks!**

**User Input:**

```
<p> Year:  <input id="YearNbrId" type="text" th:field="*{YearNbr}" /> </p>
```

**Button:**

```
<input type="button" value="Locate" id="goToDetails" />
```

**JavaScript Snippet:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var table = $('#Orders').DataTable();

$('#goToDetails').on('click', function() {
    var YearNbr = $('#YearNbrId').val();
    var url = './eData/locate?YearNbr=' + YearNbr;

    $.get(url, function(result) {
        console.log(result);

        for (var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            var myOrder = result[i];

            table.row.add([
                    null, // place holder
                    myOrder.yearNbr,
                    myOrder.orderNm,
                    '<input>', // user input
                    myOrder.model,
                    new Date(myOrder.Date).toJSON().slice(0, 10),
                    myOrder.srcCode,
                    null,
                    '<input>'
                ]).draw(false)
                .nodes()
                .to$();
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to check out the JQuery `.each` function. You probably need to do something like: `$(result).each(function(i,obj) {//code here});` Where `i` is the position in the array and `obj` is the current record in result.